# How to set top and bottom margin in .HTML using jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

how to add margin-bottom and top at multiple pages pdf .

although i am using the latest version of jspdf which uses .html function

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
let myImage = '../../../assets/logo.png';
var margins = {
top: 40,
bottom: 60,
left: 40,
width: 522
    };

doc.html(document.getElementById('htmlData'), {
callback: function (pdf) {

pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
      },
    });
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the margins variable into the `.html()`
I added it as an array below.

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
let myImage = '../../../assets/logo.png';

doc.html(document.getElementById('htmlData'), {
// Adjust your margins here (left, top, right ,bottom)
margin: [40, 60, 40, 60],
callback: function (pdf) {

pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
      },
    });
```

Comment: thank you man just one thing for display I don't want to display the content in the page html

Comment: I didn't add any code that will display content in the page html. I just tried to edit where margin array needs to be placed in the function.

Comment: The margin attribute gets ignored, there seems to be a bug https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2924